# Automatically disabling the passcode when iPhone connected to home wifi

Tags: iphone, security

Is this possibile? I have found an app for jailbroken iphones, is there something for non-jailbroken ones?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this is not possible on a non-jailbroken device. Due to sandboxing and other restrictions, it is not possible for an app on a non-jailbroken device to have control over a system-level passcode.

Comment: Thanks. Anything you can suggest to alleviate the problem?

Comment: I would like to have a password for all the apps that can potentially contain private data, basically: messages, whatsup, facebook, notes, skypes and mail.